# java.lang.NullPointerException when firing intent from certain ids

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am using an action bar to launch an intent. I am using switch statements to do so.

The application launches fine and works as intended when I use the id

```
 R.id.action_locate
```

However I want the intent to be launched from the settings menu, not an action icon. So when I change  it to it to the following:

```
R.id.action_settings
```

I get

```
 "An internal error occured during launching:

 java.lang.NullPointerException."
```

This is my onOptionsItemSelected method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle presses on the action bar items
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(viewIntent);

      return true;
   default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

and this is the XML

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_record"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_locate"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_record"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: The app isn't even starting, right? It sounds like an editor problem. Have you tried restarting it?

Comment: Yes, to no help unfortunately :(

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, check if you have anything in the "Expressions" tab in debug mode. Sometimes things there can cause it to throw a fit

Comment: strangely it worked when deleting the action_settings string and then creating it again!